# Process.Close() does not close program

Tags: c#

Here is the simple program:

```
class Program {

    static void Main(string[] args) {

        Process pr = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo prs = new ProcessStartInfo();
        prs.FileName = @"notepad.exe";
        pr.StartInfo = prs;
        pr.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        pr.Start();

        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        pr.Close(); //how do I change this to close notepad

        Console.WriteLine("press [enter] to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

How do I change this so Notepad closes?

Comment: Process.Close() isn't meant to abort the process - it's just meant to release your "local" view on the process, and associated resources.

Comment: @DJKRAZE ...I know ...that's why I'm asking the question!

Comment: you have the working answer , you're a bit late on your response.. :)

Comment: LOL well GET-ER DONE...! lol happy coding

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to MSDN, [`Process.Close()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.close.aspx) simply:

> Frees all the resources that are associated with this component.

Take a look at [`Process.Kill()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx) and [`Process.CloseMainWindow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx)

For this application, I would use:

```
pr.CloseMainWindow();
pr.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with [`Process.CloseMainWindow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow.aspx) method instead of.

> Closes a process that has a user interface by sending a close message to its main window.

Try like this;

```
Process pr = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo prs = new ProcessStartInfo();
prs.FileName = @"notepad.exe";
pr.StartInfo = prs;
pr.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
pr.Start();

Thread.Sleep(2000);

pr.CloseMainWindow();
pr.Close();

Console.WriteLine("press [enter] to exit");
Console.ReadLine();
```